# Переключение между Activity

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка Submit. Я хочу что бы при нажатии она не только, в данном случае, добавлял элемент в массив, но и возвращала на предыдущую активность. Я реализовал это так, как показано ниже.

Но кнопка не возвращает назад, а просто открывает активность "сверху". И если таким образом добавлять объекты снова и снова - таких окон поверх друг друга может скопиться огромное количество. Подскажите, как это лучше сделать?

```
public void Submit(View view) {
        MainActivity.array.add(object());

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял что вы хотите получить. Вы забыли добавить метод     finish();
Я думаю вам тут помогут фрагменты

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо вызова новой активити через интент, просто закройте текущюю через метод `finish()` - это вернет вас по стеку переходов назад на предыдущюю активити:

```
public void Submit(View view) {
    MainActivity.array.add(object());
    finish();
}
```